# Unable to install steam on Ubuntu 16.04LTS ( & Radeon R9 graphics card)

Tags: drivers, graphics, steam, radeon

I am having trouble setting up Steam on my new install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm reading that it is most likely due to my graphics card being AMD (Radeon R9).

I've tried installing a few different ways from online solutions but no joy so far.

I got it working with my previous version of Ubuntu 16 and half remember it being something to do with drivers, but I can't find the site I got the information from now.

I've downloaded the deb installer and then the following in terminal:

```
tomred@tomredPC:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
[sudo] password for tomred: 
Selecting previously unselected package steam-launcher.
(Reading database ... 251213 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack steam.deb ...
Unpacking steam-launcher (1.0.0.54) ...
Setting up steam-launcher (1.0.0.54) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
tomred@tomredPC:~/Desktop$ steam
Repairing installation, linking /home/tomred/.steam/steam to /home/tomred/.local/share/Steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you install the *libgl1-mesa-dri* package? if not: `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I put the command into terminal and got the following:

`tomred@tomredPC:~$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri`    
`Reading package lists... Done`    
`Building dependency tree`    
 `Reading state information... Done`    
`libgl1-mesa-dri is already the newest version (17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1).`    
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: ok, that's strange since libGL doesn't find the library of this package.

Comment: From researching the problem, other solutions indicated deleting these files solved the problem:
libstdc++.so.6, libgcc_s
When I deleted these however, performing the apt-get update command returned:
`apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Also when running the steam command and the libGL errors return, I can see steam running in system monitor.

Comment: Deleting **libstdc++.so.6** is not a good idea! These library is one of the most important!

Comment: I made copies before deleting. Returned them and ran upt-get update. Now back to original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions here: [support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx)

On the second reboot. The ubuntu OS gave a report of something wrong with the system and needing to send a report. It then said a report can not be sent as the AMDGPU is third party. Then I executed the usermod command and rebooted again. No messages this time.

I ran steam from the terminal and it did the update packages installation and the platform was installed completely. You might have guessed I'm pretty much guessing what I was doing here. One thing is the .aspx web page address tab keeps crashing on firefox now but displays fine on chrome.

Now Facebook messenger crashes the tab on Firefox also.

I saved the terminal output:

```
tomred@tomredPC:~$ steam
Repairing installation, linking /home/tomred/.steam/steam to /home/tomred/.local/share/Steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2018-06-24 22:04:02] Startup - updater built Nov 23 2016 01:05:42
[2018-06-24 22:04:14] Verifying installation...
[2018-06-24 22:04:14] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/tomred/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2018-06-24 22:04:14] Verification complete
[2018-06-24 22:04:14] Downloading Update...
[2018-06-24 22:04:14] Checking for available update...
[2018-06-24 22:04:15] Download failed: http error 0 (client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12)
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file tenfoot_misc_all.zip.4c0b5f375e0cf723851ad7c948769632275a4ac2 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.2f96d3383504893e85aae7d04c60b3c805c6ca86 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file tenfoot_fonts_all.zip.vz.f9f14582a5875c59b57d8d80425f4edd37ebbe25_12075417 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file tenfoot_ambientsounds_all.zip.f44dc367e90556e82ef29a6ef07a4ae4e514175b missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file tenfoot_sounds_all.zip.vz.e8ac8bf38cd88dfb418f72fa0202bd63055cf835_1215714 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file tenfoot_images_all.zip.vz.99b174b0ad8390793c8767c17fb83dd8edcec031_30748052 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file tenfoot_all.zip.vz.3fef20e0dd3dd8073bf99c6e8db1502d68fe63ea_2527244 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file resources_misc_all.zip.vz.7dd087cab4414b02abdaaa2a12d17f7fb10c0ae1_2215030 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file resources_music_all.zip.vz.fe242c2996d2eb795571a970f3a6953319513223_3707373 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file resources_hidpi_all.zip.e8baa2f3eec5ba1a23f5ab2ba49e79b1a8957269 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file resources_all.zip.vz.f696dcdd02b7d88800e88d3581d660a348f8eded_1259590 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file strings_en_all.zip.vz.2e392a40eed296fdcc66044f7a4034b89e74a361_87993 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file strings_all.zip.vz.dc59d3553613788cd26eade18bd1da34f2a81389_2253215 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file public_all.zip.vz.a9e41415cf573e289b5eb6790381b15cea81582a_760635 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file bins_ubuntu12.zip.vz.66b9f079966aef7c9ec4bb9ece2eef5abda97575_17216848 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file bins_pub_ubuntu12.zip.vz.08d98d2a52a8787daf424ab85b97be5ea3af234a_9054775 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file bins_sdk_ubuntu12.zip.vz.26902e7b17799984d132720a3631030ea83ac90e_11595868 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file bins_codecs_ubuntu12.zip.vz.5d06fa72d055c4e4f3150bad3ac39655b112a99b_2373584 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file bins_misc_ubuntu12.zip.vz.4f8753937c083960d0b329e3861ff5f9d83f2e3f_1554132 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file webkit_ubuntu12.zip.vz.a0ce116985e5f6fea1e4ce0188344e12f4797722_46863173 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file miles_ubuntu12.zip.vz.02aae1e313da8bb1d20d7fbedf09b243a468228a_295607 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file sdl2_ubuntu12.zip.vz.d5f924c08cbad4df1dfd004fd2e31e1284f46beb_613109 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file steam_ubuntu12.zip.vz.4a4f51debd28642605ca669f020d478e4af6164a_1484731 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file runtime_part0_ubuntu12.zip.4eede5a9db070a3003e90fd4370fd120a4e2fbfe missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Package file runtime_part1_ubuntu12.zip.6f5d00d3455bf4bfc54645ba541008bdc697103b missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:04:16] Downloading update (0 of 276,613 KB)...
[2018-06-24 22:04:17] Error: Download of package (tenfoot_dicts_all) failed after 0 bytes (0).
[2018-06-24 22:04:17] Downloading update (320 of 276,613 KB)...
[2018-06-24 22:04:17] Error: Download of package (resources_hidpi_all) failed after 0 bytes (0).
[2018-06-24 22:04:17] Downloading update (848 of 276,613 KB)...
[2018-06-24 22:04:17] Error: Download of package (bins_pub_ubuntu12) failed after 0 bytes (0).
[2018-06-24 22:04:17] Error: Download of package (bins_ubuntu12) failed after 0 bytes (0).
[2018-06-24 22:04:17] Downloading update (1,450 of 276,613 KB)...
[2018-06-24 22:04:17] Error: Download of package (webkit_ubuntu12) failed after 0 bytes (0).
[2018-06-24 22:04:17] Downloading update (2,231 of 276,613 KB)...
[2018-06-24 22:04:18] Error: Download of package (runtime_part0_ubuntu12) failed after 0 bytes (0).
[2018-06-24 22:04:18] Downloading update (2,928 of 276,613 KB)...
*editing out more of the same*
[2018-06-24 22:05:32] Downloading update (141,917 of 276,613 KB)...
[2018-06-24 22:05:32] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.2f96d3383504893e85aae7d04c60b3c805c6ca86 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:05:32] Package file resources_hidpi_all.zip.e8baa2f3eec5ba1a23f5ab2ba49e79b1a8957269 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:05:32] Package file bins_ubuntu12.zip.vz.66b9f079966aef7c9ec4bb9ece2eef5abda97575_17216848 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:05:32] Package file bins_pub_ubuntu12.zip.vz.08d98d2a52a8787daf424ab85b97be5ea3af234a_9054775 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:05:32] Package file webkit_ubuntu12.zip.vz.a0ce116985e5f6fea1e4ce0188344e12f4797722_46863173 missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:05:32] Package file runtime_part0_ubuntu12.zip.4eede5a9db070a3003e90fd4370fd120a4e2fbfe missing or incorrect size
[2018-06-24 22:05:33] Downloading update (142,039 of 276,613 KB)...
*editing out more of the same*
[2018-06-24 22:06:14] Downloading update (255,028 of 276,613 KB)...
[2018-06-24 22:06:15] DowInstalling breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
*editing out more of the same*Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
nloading update (255,842 of 276,613 KB)...
[2018-06-24 22:06:15] Downloading update (256,653 of 276,613 KB)...
*editing out more of the same*[2018-06-24 22:06:27] Downloading update (276,613 of 276,613 KB)...
[2018-06-24 22:06:27] Download Complete.
[2018-06-24 22:06:27] uninstalled manifest found in /home/tomred/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2018-06-24 22:06:27] Extracting package...
[2018-06-24 22:06:38] Installing update...
[2018-06-24 22:06:41] Cleaning up...
[2018-06-24 22:06:41] Update complete, launching...
[2018-06-24 22:06:41] Shutdown
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/tomred/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Found newer runtime version for 64-bit libGLU.so.1. Host: 1.3.1 Runtime: 1.3.8004
Found newer runtime version for 64-bit libSDL2-2.0.so.0. Host: 0.4.0 Runtime: 0.5.0
Found newer runtime version for 64-bit libdbusmenu-gtk.so.4. Host: 4.0.12 Runtime: 4.0.13
Found newer runtime version for 64-bit libdbusmenu-glib.so.4. Host: 4.0.12 Runtime: 4.0.13
Found newer runtime version for 64-bit libpangox-1.0.so.0. Host: 0.0.0 Runtime: 0.3000.0
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
*editing out more of the same*
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
[2018-06-24 22:07:25] Startup - updater built Jun  8 2018 22:22:23
[2018-06-24 22:07:25] Verifying installation...
[2018-06-24 22:07:25] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/tomred/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2018-06-24 22:07:25] Verification complete
[2018-06-24 22:07:25] Downloading update...
[2018-06-24 22:07:25] Checking for available updates...
[2018-06-24 22:07:26] Download complete.
[2018-06-24 22:07:26] uninstalled manifest found in /home/tomred/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2018-06-24 22:07:26] Extracting package...
[2018-06-24 22:07:37] Installing update...
[2018-06-24 22:07:53] Cleaning up...
[2018-06-24 22:07:53] Update complete, launching Steam...
[2018-06-24 22:07:53] Shutdown
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/tomred/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Pins up-to-date!
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
process 12574: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1201.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 80: saw unknown, expected number
[0624/220755.550650:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0624/220755.550706:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1528487789
[0624/220755.550710:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0624/220755.550714:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: Version with value: 20180608195629
[0624/220755.550717:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: ProductName with value: cefwebhelper
[0624/220755.550720:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
[0624/220755.560705:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1029)] Lost UI shared context.
[0624/220755.578843:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0624/220755.578873:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1528497815
[0624/220755.578884:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0624/220755.578895:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: Version with value: 20180608195629
[0624/220755.578906:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: ProductName with value: cefwebhelper
[0624/220755.578918:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
[S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; create pipe failed.[S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; create pipe failed.[S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; create pipe failed.Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 0 milliseconds to initialize
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
CApplicationManagerPopulateThread took 0 milliseconds to initialize (will have waited on CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
PulseAudio connect failed (used only for Mic Volume Control) with error: Access denied
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
[0624/220815.411837:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0624/220815.411912:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1528487789
[0624/220815.411916:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0624/220815.411919:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: Version with value: 20180608195629
[0624/220815.411922:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: ProductName with value: cefwebhelper
[0624/220815.411925:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
Generating new string page texture 12: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 13: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311.30 KB
Generating new string page texture 14: 128x256, total string texture memory is 442.37 KB
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 769
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561197960265728 [API loaded no]
[0624/220815.831863:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(254)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
process 12690: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1201.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Found unsupported CDM version 1.4.9.1088, using last known good version 1.4.8.1008
Generating new string page texture 21: 64x256, total string texture memory is 507.90 KB
[0624/220819.378530:ERROR:web_plugin_impl.cc(38)] Widevine registration is not supported after context initialization
Could not create Vulkan device: 
ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
Generating new string page texture 22: 8x256, total string texture memory is 516.10 KB
Generating new string page texture 23: 16x256, total string texture memory is 532.48 KB
Generating new string page texture 24: 24x256, total string texture memory is 557.06 KB
Generating new string page texture 25: 32x256, total string texture memory is 589.82 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Generating new string page texture 33: 384x256, total string texture memory is 983.04 KB
Generating new string page texture 36: 256x256, total string texture memory is 1.25 MB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
roaming config store loaded successfully - 1361 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
ExecCommandLine: "'/home/tomred/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam'"
System startup time: 66.94 seconds
Generating new string page texture 99: 128x256, total string texture memory is 131.07 KB
Generating new string page texture 100: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1.38 MB
Generating new string page texture 115: 256x256, total string texture memory is 393.22 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Generating new string page texture 120: 256x256, total string texture memory is 1.64 MB
Generating new string page texture 121: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1.77 MB
Generating new string page texture 122: 256x256, total string texture memory is 2.03 MB
Generating new string page texture 123: 64x256, total string texture memory is 2.10 MB
Generating new string page texture 125: 128x256, total string texture memory is 2.23 MB
Generating new string page texture 141: 1024x256, total string texture memory is 3.28 MB
Generating new string page texture 142: 128x256, total string texture memory is 3.41 MB
Generating new string page texture 143: 256x256, total string texture memory is 3.67 MB
Generating new string page texture 144: 512x256, total string texture memory is 4.19 MB
Generating new string page texture 146: 48x256, total string texture memory is 4.24 MB
Generating new string page texture 147: 128x256, total string texture memory is 4.37 MB
Generating new string page texture 148: 256x256, total string texture memory is 4.64 MB
Generating new string page texture 151: 256x256, total string texture memory is 4.90 MB
[0624/220922.451205:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(2921)] Received HEADERS for invalid stream 1
Generating new string page texture 155: 64x256, total string texture memory is 458.75 KB
Generating new string page texture 161: 128x256, total string texture memory is 5.03 MB
Generating new string page texture 165: 1024x256, total string texture memory is 6.08 MB
GameAction [AppID 242860, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp failed with AppError_18 with ""
GameAction [AppID 242860, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to Failed with ""
GameAction [AppID 242860, ActionID 2] : InstallApps waiting for user response to ShowEula "https://store.steampowered.com//eula/242860_eula_0"
GameAction [AppID 242860, ActionID 2] : InstallApps continues with user response "ShowEula"
GameAction [AppID 242860, ActionID 2] : InstallApps changed task to CreateNextApp with ""
Refresh rate: 0
*editing out more of the same*
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rasaving roaming config store to 'sharedconfig.vdf'
roaming config store 2 saved successfully
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
GameAction [AppID 242860, ActionID 2] : InstallApps changed task to RemoveGameDemos with ""
GameAction [AppID 242860, ActionID 2] : InstallApps changed task to CreateSystemEntries with ""
GameAction [AppID 242860, ActionID 2] : InstallApps changed task to AutoLaunch with ""
GameAction [AppID 242860, ActionID 2] : InstallApps changed task to Complete with ""
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
GameAction [AppID 242860, ActionID 3] : LaunchApp changed task to DownloadingDepots with ""
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
```